# Running JUnit Tests Command Line

Tags: java, junit

I have two files: thing.java and thingTester.java, the latter is using the methods defined in the "thing" class so I can test those methods.

In addition to those two files, I have junit-4.12.jar in the same directory, so I have only those 3 files in my working directory.

Compiled using this (on Unix):

```
javac -cp .:junit-4.12.jar thingTester.java thing.java
```

Trying to run using the line below, but I get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError":

```
java -cp .:junit-4.12.jar junit.textui.TestRunner thingTester thing
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't really find any clear documentation or general examples.

Comment: please show your class definitions at a minimum

Comment: Have you considered using a build system such s `Gradle`? Then you can just run: `gradlew test` for all your testing needs.

Comment: Maven would make your life so much easier.